# Alternative to list command in postgres for scripting

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, psql

Unfortunatly `psql -l` uses linewraps

**example**
see output and regard the "access" column

> ```
>                                           List of databases
>           Name           |   Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
> -------------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
>  firstdb                 | postgres   | UTF8     | de_DE.UTF-8 | de_DE.UTF-8 |
>  secnddb                 | scnduser   | UTF8     | de_DE.UTF-8 | de_DE.UTF-8 |
>  thrddb                  | scnduser   | UTF8     | de_DE.UTF-8 | de_DE.UTF-8 |
>  postgres                | postgres   | UTF8     | de_DE.UTF-8 | de_DE.UTF-8 |
>  template0               | postgres   | UTF8     | de_DE.UTF-8 | de_DE.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
>                          |            |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
>  template1               | postgres   | UTF8     | de_DE.UTF-8 | de_DE.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
>                          |            |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
> (6 rows)
> ```

**hint** even with some option, I can't get that gone:

> ```
> $ psql -Atlqn
> firstdb|postgres|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|
> secnddb|scnduser|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|
> thrddb|scnduser|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|
> postgres|postgres|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|
> template0|postgres|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|=c/postgres
> postgres=CTc/postgres
> template1|postgres|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|=c/postgres
> postgres=CTc/postgres
> ```

**Question** Is there another way to get the list of databases in the same way `\list` prints it so I can use it in scripts for parsing with e.g. awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting issue. You're being bitten by hard linewraps in ACL entries.  Those aren't the only place they can appear btw, just the most common.

### Use a null-byte recordsep

Rather than trying to avoid the newlines, why not use a different record separator? A null byte (`\0`) can be good; that's what the `-0` option is for. It's only useful if your client can deal with null bytes, though; good for `xargs -0`, not good for lots of other stuff. The handy thing about a null byte is that it won't appear in `psql`'s output otherwise so there's no risk of conflict. `gawk` does support null-separated records, though it's woefully underdocumented.

Try, e.g:

```
psql -Atlqn -0  | gawk -vRS=$'\0' '{ gsub("\n", " "); print }
```

which replaces newlines in database names (yes, they can appear there!), ACL entries, etc with a space.

### Use a different recordsep

Alternately, use `-R`, e.g. `-R '!'` or `-R '--SEPARATOR--'` or whatever is easy for you to parse and not likely to appear in the output.

### Query the catalogs yourself, escaping strings

Depending on the information you need, you can instead query the catalogs or `information_schema` directly, too. You'll still have to deal with funny chars, so you may want a regexp to escape any funny business.

### Newlines and shell metacharacters

Beware that you still have to deal with unexpected newlines; consider what happens when some @#$@ does this:

```
 CREATE DATABASE "my
 database";
```

Yes, that's a legal database name. So are both of:

```
 CREATE DATABASE "$(rm -rf /gladthisisnotroot);";

 CREATE DATABASE "$(createuser -l -s my_haxxor -W top_secret)"
```

Yes, both are legal database names. Yes, that's really, really bad if you don't escape your shell metacharacters properly, you made the mistake of running your shell scripts as root or the `postgres` user, and they're not feeling nice.

Comment: psql 9.1.1 seems not to support -0 it's supported from 9.2+ postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html but thanks, yes this works: `psql -Atlqn -F\| -R'~~SEP~~' | awk 'BEGIN{ FS="|"; RS="~~SEP~~";}{ print "nl:"$0 }'`

Answer (score 2):

All relevant data is in `pg_database` and `pg_user`
see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-database.html

```
select pg_database.datname,pg_user.usename,pg_encoding_to_char(pg_database.encoding),pg_database.datcollate,pg_database.datctype,pg_database.datacl from pg_database,pg_user WHERE pg_database.datdba = pg_user.usesysid;
```

on shell, wrapped in psql command:

```
psql -AStnq -c "select [...]"
```

returns correct formatted

```
template1|postgres|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|{=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}
template0|postgres|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|{=c/postgres,postgres=CTc/postgres}
postgres|postgres|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|
firstdb|postgres|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|
secnddb|scnduser|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|
thrddb|scnduser|UTF8|de_DE.UTF-8|de_DE.UTF-8|
```

Comment: This won't protect you from a newline (or worse) in `datname` though.